# Is there a way to enable Instant app deep link without upgrading links in Google play

Tags: android, deep-linking, instant

I find the Google Approach for Instant Apps terrible from user perspective (and from developer view as well, btw)

The Instant app, if I understood properly, was to improve the user experience enabling the use of Apps without installation (like a fire and forget)
Deep linking is a step further to get this kind of experience attached to an URL you own. Great!
But... every user has to enable deep links on their Google play account as by default this is turned off. And the user experience improvement turned to be a failure.

Except if I missed something.

So here is my question, is there any way to have instant app deep link working on any recent phone without having to explain users: go to your Google Play settings, Click on General etc...

I've red for example that instant apps works anyway for Google Play Branded links

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not resolved so far.